# Assembly Injection into Live Processes (Mono)

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I've recently came across the blog article [Monovation: Assembly Injection into Live Processes](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Sep-29.html) of Miguel de Icaza.

I've tried to reproduce it with no luck. My command line was

'csharp --attach 5612'

where 5612 was the pid of a simple running mono 'Hello World' console application.
I've got an exception (see the stack trace above).

What I've tried so far:

- using Mono 2.10.8 (csharp and csharp2 commands for .NET 4 and 2 )
- using Mono 3.2.3 (only csharp command exists)

Q1: Missed I something?

Q2: Is it possible that this virtual machine attach facility (see [Monovation: Assembly Injection into Live Processes](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Sep-29.html)) is available only in Linux installations? (I am using Windows 7) It sounds an easy answer, but Miguel does not mention platform restriction in his article, and the whole point of mono is the multiplatform, is not it? So I can not believe it so easy.

Q3: What about Mac? Is there any chance it will work in a Mac, or we must look elsewhere?

Thx in advance

Stack trace:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for     Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall ---> System.EntryPointNotFoundException:    Mono_Posix_Syscall_get_at_fdcwd
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall:get_at_fdcwd ()
  at Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Unix.UnixUserInfo.GetRealUserId () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Unix.UnixUserInfo.GetRealUser () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Attach.VirtualMachine.Attach (System.String agent, System.String args)  [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.ClientCSharpShell..ctor (Mono.CSharp.Evaluator evaluator, Int32 pid) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was  thrown by the type initializer for Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall --->  System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Mono_Posix_Syscall_get_at_fdcwd
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall:get_at_fdcwd ()
  at Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Unix.UnixUserInfo.GetRealUserId () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Unix.UnixUserInfo.GetRealUser () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Attach.VirtualMachine.Attach (System.String agent, System.String args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.ClientCSharpShell..ctor (Mono.CSharp.Evaluator evaluator, Int32 pid) [0x00000]  in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: The usage of `Mono.Unix` means rather clearly that it was not intended for use on Windows.

Comment: Stephane, thx for your note. I've noticed the ominous Unix namespace, just do not want to believe that such a platform dependency exist. Also the command 'csharp' is definitely from the Windows distribution, and it definitely parses the --attach command line parameter. If it is such obivous that --attach requires Unix, then why not gives us a correct error message (compiled with platform conditional directive) that 'Using --attach command line switch requires platform A, B, C'